Why can't I log in when interacting with the controller?
The framework I am using is .Net 8 Blazor Web App. And the authentication is based on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework .
I want the ValidationMessage dynamic update but HttpContext/SignInManager/UserManager are not supported by rendermode InteractiveServer.
Now I try to send a Json to a controller to implement this.
I implemented the register page by this successfully (without auto login in).
However, when I try the same way with login page, I meet a strange problem that it can not login.
Here is the code of razor page:
@inject IHttpClientFactory _HttpClientFactory
@inject IStringLocalizer<Login> _Localizer
<EditForm Model="_Input" method="post" OnValidSubmit="LoginUser" FormName="login" Enhance class="Flex">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div id="SubmitDiv" class="FlexAll">
        <InputText @bind-Value="_Input.Email" class="ant-input SubmitContentInput" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" placeholder="@_Localizer["ErrorMessageUserNameRequire"]" />
        <ValidationMessage For="() => _Input.Email" class="ant-form-item-explain-error" />
        <InputText @bind-Value="_Input.Password" type="password" class="ant-input SubmitContentInput" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true" placeholder="@_Localizer["ErrorMessagePasswordRequire"]" />
        <ValidationMessage For="() => _Input.Password" class="ant-form-item-explain-error" />
    </div>    
        <button type="submit" class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary Flex">@_Localizer["Login"]</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>
[SupplyParameterFromForm]
private LoginModel _Input { get; set; } = new();
 public async Task LoginUser()
 {
     var httpClient = _HttpClientFactory.CreateClient();
     var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<LoginModel>($"{_NavigationManager.BaseUri}Login/Login", this._Input);

     if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
         var result = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<LoginResultModel>();
         if (result is { })
         {
             switch (result.LoginResultType)
             {
                 case LoginResultModel.LoginResultTypeEnum.Success:
                     {
                         _NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
                         return;
                     }                
             }
         }
         else
         {
             await _Message.Error(_Localizer["UnableToLogInNormally"].Value);
         }
     }
 }

And here is the controller:
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class LoginController:Controller
{
    readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _SignInManager;
    readonly ILogger<Login> _Logger;        
    public LoginController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<Login> logger)
    { 
        _SignInManager = signInManager;
        _Logger = logger;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<LoginResultModel>> Login([FromBody] LoginModel login)
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        LoginResultModel _loginResult = new LoginResultModel();
        var result = await _SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(login.Email, login.Password, login.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result. Succeeded)
        {
            _Logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            _loginResult.LoginResultType = LoginResultModel.LoginResultTypeEnum.Success;
            return _loginResult;
        }
        else if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            _loginResult.LoginResultType = LoginResultModel.LoginResultTypeEnum.RequiresTwoFactor;
            _loginResult.QueryParameter = new() { ["rememberMe"] = login.RememberMe };
            return _loginResult;               
        }
        else if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _loginResult.LoginResultType = LoginResultModel.LoginResultTypeEnum.LockedOut;                
            return _loginResult;
        }
        else
        {
            _loginResult.LoginResultType = LoginResultModel.LoginResultTypeEnum.InvalidLoginAttempt;
            return _loginResult;
        }
    }

I tried to get the result of SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync in the controller by break point and it is logged in successfully.
However, in AutherizeView it still is the view that not logged in:
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <div class="page">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <NavMenu />
            </div>

            <main>
                <div class="top-row px-4">
                    <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/" target="_blank">@_Localizer["Test"]</a>
                </div>
                <article class="content px-4">
                    @Body
                </article>
            </main>
        </div>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <Login></Login>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

What's wrong with my code?

I tried another way by using AuthenticationStateProvider in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmAnSNfFGsc&ab_channel=CuriousDrive%3ASolveCodingChallenges.WinPrizes.
Here is my code:
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {            
        var _user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
        return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_user));
    }
    public void MarkUserAsAuthored(string eMail)
    {
        var _identity= new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,eMail) }, "apiauth_type");
        var _user = new ClaimsPrincipal(_identity);
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_user)));
    }
}

After SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync logined successfully, runs
((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)_AuthenticationStateProvider).MarkUserAsAuthored(login.Email);

However, no matter the code above runs in razor page or controller, it doesn't work any also.

Because the Identity application cookie is not set in the browser(F12 in the browser and check the Application window).
You may consider getting the response cookie from HttpClient and manually set it. But another thing you need to know that you cannot set cookies from a Blazor server-side session. You do not have access to the HttpContext and there isn't the traditional request/response cycle that you can use to return cookies in the response headers.

@Rena I have read a lot of tutorials recently, and later I found that it would be more appropriate to use JWT authentication with a custom AuthenticationStateProvider and localstorge. But I really can’t figure out why my AuthenticationStateProvider authentication is successful (confirmed through breakpoints), but AuthorizeView does not display the View after successful authentication at all.

@Rena And also, I found that if I change the render mode from InteractiveServer to InteractiveAuto, then the AuthenticationStateProvider works. It stands to reason that both are based on blazor server, but I don't understand why InteractiveServer doesn't work but InteractiveAuto does.
